# Proxy object no ejecuta mi handler

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo proxy y quiero interceptar el cambio a la propiedad pi para multiplicarla por 2 y que ese sea el valor final pero no he podido conseguirlo

```js
    const obj = {pi: 31.1}
        const proxy = new Proxy(obj,{set: function(object,prop,value){
            console.log("change")
            object[prop] = value * 2
            return true
        }});

        obj["pi"] = 30.23
console.log(obj["pi"])
```

No me funciona, no se porque, debería ser 60.46 el valor de la propiedad pi, gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0):

El problema se da porque estas utilizando la variable `obj` y no el resultado devuelto por `new Proxy`.

#### Solución:

Necesitas trabajar con el objeto devuelto por `new Proxy`, por ejemplo, así:

```js
const obj = new Proxy({
  pi: 31.1
}, {
  set: function(object, prop, value) {
    object[prop] = prop == 'pi' ? value * 2 : value;
    return true;
  }
});

obj["pi"] = 30.23
console.log(obj["pi"])
```